# Python3 Fixing :"TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

Cant seem to figure out what has happened, I converted all my matrices to float and still giving me an error.

Im trying to implement the gauss-seidel (no relaxation) method for linear equation solving according to "pseudo-Code" given by my professor

```
a=((-5.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,0.0),
   (3.0,-6.0,3.0,0.0,0.0),
   (0.0,3.0,-6.0,3.0,0.0),
   (0.0,0.0,3.0,-6.0,3.0),
   (0.0,0.0,0.0,3.0,-5.0))
b=(-80.0,0.0,0.0,60.0,0.0)


def norelax(a,b,k_max,precisao):
    n=5
    erro_max=200.0
    k=0
    x=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]


    while abs(erro_max)>precisao and k<k_max:
        for i in range(0,n):
            soma_antes=0
            for j in range(0,i):
                soma_antes+=a[i][j]*x[j]
            soma_depois=0
            for j in range(i+1,n):
                soma_depois+=a[i][j]*x[j]
            x[i]=(b[i]-soma_antes-soma_depois)/a[i][i]
            print(x)
            x_anterior=x[i]
            erro_max=max(x[i]-x_anterior[i]/x[i])
            print(x)
        k+=1
    return x

print(norelax(a,b,300,0.0001))
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Abraços BR HUE HUE

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? It's likely that either `a`, `b`, `x`, or `x_anterior` is actually a float, and you using the notation `[i]` is causing this error.

Comment: `x_anterior` is presumably a float as you define `x_anterior=x[i]` and in the next line try to address `x_anterior[i]`

Comment: x_anterior is 16.0 at the time you try to use x_anterior[0] in a calculation. The error message is pretty explicit.